# Tailwind: text-overflow: ellipsis?

Tags: css, overflow, tailwind-css

Is there a way to use

```
text-overflow: ellipsis
```

Thought the [Tailwind CSS Framework](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/what-is-tailwind/)

I would like to use the tailwind convention like :

```
&__title {
    @apply text-overflow-ellipsis;
}
```

Instead of

```
&__title {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: well have you searched the docs about `text-overflow` ? as far as i know tailwind uses something like `@apply .text-transparent` for text-color. If you find something in the docs about `text-overflow` then you can use it, otherwise you are out of luck

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes I already did a lot of search about the Tailwind docs but unfortunately I was unable to find any solutions

Comment: text-overflow: ellipsis; cannot be used alone, Along with text-overflow, you should other properties like overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap; also. You can use .truncate class to achieve this. Here is the link from the documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/whitespace-and-wrapping

Comment: @AKNair you should write this comment in an answer so the OP can accept it

Comment: Oh Shall I do that now?

Comment: It could be great yes if you have time, if some others developers are also interested by the answer of this post in the future

Comment: @Ced - I have updated this as an answer. If this has resolved your query, please upvote it. Thanks Mihai for the suggestion.

Comment: I did it, thanks to both of you guys for your help !

Comment: Come on guys, can the SO community stop downgrading questions without any reasons ....

Answer (score 22, accepted):

CSS property `text-overflow: ellipsis;` **cannot be used alone.**

Along with text-overflow, you should use other properties like:

```
overflow: hidden; 
white-space: nowrap;
```

You can use `.truncate` class to achieve this. Here is the link from the   [Tailwind documentation.](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break/#truncate)

Solution of the initial problem:

```
&__title {
    @apply truncate;
}
```

Comment: Hey! I have been banned to ask question, I find this sanction harsh. I need positive upvote could you please Sir help me in my long quest by just upvoting my question, because negative result get me blocking for asking any more question, and on the other side I cannot delete any because I already accepted and upvoted your awesome answer, so I'm stuck and feel bad. thank you for your comprehension and I wish you a nice day !

Answer (score 16):

Use class truncate

```
<div class="overflow-hidden truncate w-2">Long long long text</div>
```

See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/word-break/#app

`overflow-hidden` will hide overlaps, `truncate` adds ellipsis and optional `w-2` set width

Comment: `truncate` in tailwind includes `overflow-hidden` so no need to write it manually

Answer (score 9):

Tailwind `truncate` will only truncate one line, and includes the following out of the box:

[image]

If you need flexibility in # of lines, I suggest installing [tailwindcss-line-clamp](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-line-clamp) and using line-clamp-X, which also has everything you need within.

[image]

Comment: It's worth mentioning that tailwindcss/line-clamp is an **official Tailwind CSS plugin**. There's a nice explainer on how to use it [here](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/multi-line-truncation-with-tailwindcss-line-clamp).

Comment: As of Tailwind CSS v3.3 the line-clamp utilities are now included in the framework by default and this plugin is no longer required.

Answer (score 3):

truncate with width
eg:
`<div className="truncate w-32 text-left text-lightBlack capitalize">display name</div>`